# Specify which Property goes between the opening and closing tag in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Consider the following Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox>Text</TextBox>
    <Button>Content</Button>
</Grid>
```

It will set the

- Text Property of a TextBox *(only WPF)*
- Content Property of a Button
- Children Property of a Grid

But how is this specified? How do you specify which Property that goes between the opening and closing tag in Xaml?
Is this set by some metadata in the Dependency Property or what?

Thanks

Comment: that's a good question, I wondered about that as well.

Comment: Just a point of fact you can't actually do that with a `TextBox`.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: `<TextBox>Text</TextBox>` works great. What do you mean? Looking at TextBox.cs with Reflector I can see that is has `ContentProperty("Text")`

Comment: Only in WPF not in Silverlight or WP7.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I see, you're right :) As usual, things doesn't work the same in Silverlight. Good input, I'll edit the question and change it into something that works for Silverlight and WP7 as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a `ContentPropertyAttribute` that is applied to a class.  WPF/Silverlight will use reflection to determine which property to use.

If you want to do this with a custom class, you can do it like so:

```
[ContentProperty("Bar")]
public class Foo : Control
{
    public static DependencyProperty BarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Bar",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(Foo),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetaData(0));

    public int Bar
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(BarProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then you could specify it in XAML like so:

```
<lcl:Foo>12</lcl:Foo>
```

**Update**

Since it is using reflection, you don't really need to do a DependencyProperty. For instance, this will also work:

```
[ContentProperty("Bar")]
public class Foo : Control
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The bit about `ContentProperty` is correct however at least in Silverlight and WP7 the property specified does not need to be a dependency property.  Silverlight/WP7 merely uses reflection to find the Property specified by the `ContentProperty` attribute so the content property can be any property whose type can be parsed by Xaml.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Good point. I updated the answer to show that any property can be used.

Comment: I think there's an error in your sample. The closing tag also needs to specify the namespace, doesn't it?